# Where to put lapack/blas binaries in Anaconda install?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, lapack, blas

Scipy is installed with Anaconda, but won't work since no lapack and blas resources can be found. I've put the precompiled lapack/blas stuff from this link:

http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvobod2/misc/lapack/

into my Anaconda folder (user/anaconda) and also into my standard python istallation (c://python27). It still won't work.

I've checked out other questions on this forum on how to install. I've followed the instructions given here:

http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html

but Cmake always sais that the compiler can't compile a simple test program.

Comment: Never had this kind of issue, neither with windows nor with Linux. Anaconda usually contains the necessary libraries.

Comment: can you specify `won't work`?

Comment: Won't work means that when I import Scipy it gives me: ImportError: No module named scipy

Comment: I figure this is since there is no lapack/blas because when I pip install scipy it tells me that there are no blas/lapack resources. However when I conda install scipy, the feedback prompt sais that the package is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this code?

`-conda install -c pymc pymc`

It includes installing Scipy. 
"Lapack/blas resources not found" error disappeared when I tried this.

Comment: That you for the answer. I just tried it, but I still can't import scipy. I'm trying to uninstall the vanilla Python 2.7 installation that I have, perhaps the problem is that I have both anaconda and the vanilla version...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I uninstalled Python 2.7 and Anaconda, and now for some reason it works. Thanks to you guys who answered this post :)